# how to use cin.ignore in a loop

Tags: c++

the `readMe.ingredients` is a pointer to an array of Ingredient objects that has an overloaded >> operator.  The delimiter for the >> operator is a newline character.

Suppose the list of ingredients is formatted like this:

- 4 gal chocolate ice cream
- 3 gal butterscotch syrup
- 12 pint sliced
  bananas

---

```
for (int count = 0; count < readMe.numIngredients; count++)
    {
        in >> readMe.ingredients[count];
        // the loop continues until you finish with all of the ingredients
    }
    in.ignore(10000,'\n');
```

That's some example code for parsing the ingredient list above.  But wouldn't you want `in.ignore(10000,'\n')` ***inside*** the loop instead of outside in order for this to work?  If not, then why should it be outside?

Comment: This is c++, not C, tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind I think I got it.  There's a blank line after the ingredient list

But wouldn't you still want `in.ignore(10000,'\n')` in the loop in order to go to the next line?  Wouldn't it just keep assigning `4 gal chocolate ice cream` to each item in the array?

Comment: Yes, the delimiter is the newline, but the delimiter gets "read" out of the input buffer.  That's how the function knows to return.  So you don't have to explicitly read the newlines with formatted input functions.